# How can I pass data from the current Activity to a paused Activity?

Tags: android

I want to know how to pass data from the current Activity to a paused Activity.

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's call the paused Activity "A" and the "current" Activity "B".

The way to have B communicate results to A is for A to call `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`, and for B to use `setResult()` to provide the return value(s). A then receives those return values in `onActivityResult()`.

Answer (score 3):

in your current activity, create an intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PausedActivity.class);
i.putExtra(key, value);
startActivity(i);
```

then in paused activity, retrieve those values.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null) {
    String value = extras.getString(key);
}
```

if the data is complex, try [http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/framework.html#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441871/passing-data-of-a-non-primitive-type-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: thanks for response.

I think this code will be used for creating new intent of PausedActivity. I use it when finish current Activity and create new activity.

It is not passing data to Paused Activity.

My code is little different :

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", "value");
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();

I wanna pass a value direcly from current activity to Paused Activity (previous activity) without new intent.

Thanks.

Comment: i believe commonsware.com's answer is the best way to solve this problem. your alternative is to store the results in a database and when the paused activity is resumed, you retrieve those results.