# Why does this intent return a hasmap?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, classcastexception, serializable

I'm trying to send an object from one Activity to another.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
//Send the intent to ChallengeViewActivity class
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChallengeViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Challenge", currentChallenge); // currentChallenge is a Challenge object
    context.startActivity(intent);
   }
```

So over at the receiving class: ChallengeViewActivity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Challenge challenge = (Challenge)intent.getExtras().getSerializable("Challenge");
```

This throws a:

> ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to
>   alm.motiv.AlmendeMotivator.models.Challenge

I have no clue why java think I want to cast this to a hash map. If you could give me some insight and a possible solution to this problem I'd be really gratefull!

Comment: are you sure currentChallenge is not an `HashMap`?

Comment: Make your Challenge Object Serializale and then you are able to get it, by doing a cast to Challenge.

Comment: You should let your Challenge implements Parcelable instead. This is the best way to pass "complex objects" from one Activity to another.

Comment: The class Challenge implements Serializable. currentChallenge is a Challenge object. Still for some reason I get this error

Comment: I've also read lots about the Serializable vs Parselable debate. Isn't it possible with Serializable?

Comment: @KevinGroen Yes, it is possible with Serilizable

Comment: @KevinGroen It is possible, but not recommended: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611843/is-using-serializable-in-android-bad/3612364#3612364