# Measuring performance with parcelable

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, parcelable

Currently, I am having around 100 Pojo's which implements serializable and passed throughout the app, Since I am expecting more to come as the app grows & it will be better to make use of parcelable.

Will there be any significant performance gain and how can I measure it?

I know about android studio profiler etc. but not really aware which area I will see the performance gain i.e overall app speed, memory consumption etc.

Also, any thing to take care of while making this change?

Comment: Some of the answers here will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323074/4465208

Answer (score 1):

According to [Philippe Breault's benchmark](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/), `Parcelable` is way faster than `Serializable`. He tested it on 3 different devices, with Android versions 2.3.3 and 4.2.2.

You can see the results below.

[image: benchmark]

- Nexus 10 Serializable: 1.0004ms – Parcelable: 0.0850ms - 10.16x faster.
- Nexus 4 Serializable: 1.8539ms – Parcelable: 0.1824ms - 11.80x faster.
- Desire Z Serializable: 5.1224ms – Parcelable: 0.2938ms - 17.36x faster.

Those numbers are for a single object, passed through a `Bundle` 1000 times around. If you're expecting to add 100+ more, things will escalate quickly.

`Serializable` is a standard Java interface, and it tends to leave a lot of temporary objects behing, which can trigger many GC events.

`Parcelable` on the other hand, is an Android interface, that was conceived to tackle performance issues, and it achieves that by not using reflection on the serialization. Thing is, you have to define the serialization yourself. But you'll get a huge performance difference compared to `Serializable` objects.

You can read more about `Parcelable` [on the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable).

Also, [related answer on why you should use Parcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3612364/4070469).