# Android: How to Pass WebView from one Activity to another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to pass the WebView from One activity to another Activity.
how to do that.  I referred [How do I pass an object from one activity to another on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906925/android-how-do-i-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another) 
but still not getting any idea for this. Please help me to get this....

Comment: I have declared the WebView as public. Now i can access that webview anywhere and i can load the result in this webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either u try to use `finish()` an the passed Activity or you simply call `finish()` in the activity after it's done with it's calculations

Comment: After Calling the Finish(), then how can i get the result. Please explain

Comment: you could set it in a static variable via setter in your java (not activity) class. but just btw: why do u want to use an activity for calculations? I think it's not the intended way.

Comment: in this case your choice would be a static variable or a broadcastReceiver to make this work. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you may want a broadcast receiever... 
try looking here: [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

That will let one activity send a message to another

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want that in an Android activity, not just a normal Java class?

Comment: Sample.java is normal java class. from this i started the second activity.

Comment: My point is that you should only use an Activity when you are displaying something to the user or getting input from the user. If the class is only doing calcuations it shouldn't be an Activity.

Comment: actually i'm doing the Camera activity in the new activity , from this i have to pass the captured image url to html page. Otherwise tell me how to send current webview to new Activity while starting this(from sample.java)