# refresh an arraylist in the second intent

Tags: java, android, android-layout, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I'm making an app that receive datas from a webservice with an android app that have 2 views.

The first ask the login and the password. Then the activity request to the webservice, and if there is datas, he create an intent that shows the datas in a listview:

Main

```
private ArrayList accountlist = new ArrayList();
...
accountlist.add(...)
...
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Second.class);
intent.putExtra("accountlist", accountlist);
intent.putExtra("login", loginEditText.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("pass", passwordEditText.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

Second

```
private ArrayList accountlist;
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ...
 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.results,accountlist));
 ...
}
private void refresh() {
 ...
 accountlist.add(...)
 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.results,accountlist));
}
```

The result is that I have the items that are addes into the current list (e.g I have 2 items, if I refresh 4 times, I will have 10 items in the view and I wand only the 2 last)

If you have an idea :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just used the

```
accountlist.clear();
```

methid just after

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Second.class);
intent.putExtra("accountlist", accountlist);
intent.putExtra("login", loginEditText.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("pass", passwordEditText.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

to clear the list that will be re-used to launch the intent!

Answer (score 0):

you can't pass an ArrayList directly between activity, you have to go to kind of object by serializing. read this: [How do I pass an object from one activity to another on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906925/android-how-do-i-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another)

Comment: ArrayList implements Serializable, so its perfectly valid to pass it between activities.

Comment: @julien : It's not the problem, it's work perfectly, but in the refresh method (2nd class/intent), I want to delete and clear the items already on the list and then add the news one (end not just add new ones)

Comment: @clement, in the refresh() method why don't you do a accountlist.clear() before you do a accountlist.add(..).

Comment: @Prabhu : it was not in the refresh method but in the first intent (not the second one)

Thanks to illuminate me :-)