# Sending an object to another class via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

How do you pass an object between views in an android application. I have googled and found that your class needs to implement the appropriate interface. How though do we do it if we do not own the class/object type we are passing (for example from an external library or a random class within the sdk)

I need to pass a HtmlSelect item object (from HtmlUnit open source project) to another class to process it but I cant bundle it up.

Thanks

Comment: there are posts on SO that discuss this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906925/android-how-do-i-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is you create a static helper object and pass it like that.

```
HelperObject class {
    static HtmlSelect myHtmlObject
}
```

source activity:

```
HelperObject.myHtmlObject = currentHtlmlObject;
startActivity(intent);
```

Destination activity:

```
onCreate() {
    HtmlSelect htmlSelect = "create a copy copy of HelperObject.myHtmlObject not to have problems and then set it to null"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `putExtra()` method of your `Intent` to pass parameters.

At times you need to first "deconstruct" your object into simple elements (Strings, Integers) and then reconstitute it at the other end with `getExtras()`.

Comment: But what if you can't deconstruct your object easily, or if your object contains 100 fields?