# Using the same object at the same time from the different Activity classes

Tags: android

I use Handler to send/receive messages(data type integers) from the queue. At this moment I use the received data from the queue in Activity class. But I want to use this received data at same time in different Activity classes. How do I achieve this in Android?

Comment: do i have to implement an adapter pattern? like in Java using an adapter class.

Comment: Could you not make a static class to hold the needed information? Or save it in a file, and then have each part of your code that needs it load it? I dont really know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is what i want to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906925/android-how-do-i-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another

Comment: I been able to use Seriazable interface to send object from one view to another. My problem is right the when i call extras.getSeriazable, the second view get's only constant value. How do i solve this?