# get imageurl on click of image of gridview

Tags: android, android-activity

I have making  android app in which fetching the image from database(MYSQL) using php.I get the images also but problem is that i want to pass the image to another activity i.e from gridview to viewflipper so to slide image.

please any one can help me to how to pass clicked image which fetch from database.

Thanks in advance.

**DisplayActivity.java**

public class DisplayImages extends Activity{

```
ImageView imageview;
JSONObject json1= JSONfunction.getJSONfromURL("http://www.zxxxxcssxxxxxx.com/app/photo.php");
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_images);

        JSONArray catgry = null;
    try {
        catgry = json1.getJSONArray("photo");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   final GridView gridView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
   ImageAdapter adapter=new ImageAdapter(this,catgry);
   gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


   /**
    * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
    * */

   gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new  OnItemClickListener(){

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Image img=new Image();
        Object imagename=view.getTag();

        if(position==0)
        img.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap("http://www.aaa.com/thumb_photo_3.jpg"));
        if(position==1)
            img.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap("http://www.aaa.com/thumb_photo_4.jpg"));
        if(position==2)
            img.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap("http:/www.aaa.com/thumb_photo_5.jpg"));
        if(position==3)
            img.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap("http://www.aaa.com/thumb_photo_6.jpg"));
        if(position==4)
            img.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap("http://www.aaa.com/thumb_photo_7.jpg"));
        if(position==5)
            img.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap("http://www.aaa.com/thumb_photo_8.jpg"));
        if(position==6)
            img.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap("http://www.aaa.com/thumb_photo_9.jpg"));
        if(position==7)
            img.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap("http://www.aaa.com/thumb_photo_10.jpg"));
        if(position==8)
            img.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap("http://www.aaa.com/thumb_photo_11.jpg"));
        if(position==9)
            img.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap("http://www.aaa.com/thumb_photo_12.jpg"));
        if(position==10)
            img.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap("http://www.aaa.com/thumb_photo_13.jpg"));

        Toast.makeText(DisplayImages.this, "" + imagename,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FullSizeImageActivity.class);
        //Create Parcelable object
        ParcelableImage parcelableImage=new ParcelableImage(img);

        //store Parcelable Object in intent
        intent.putExtra("img", parcelableImage);
        startActivity(intent); 
    }

   });
}

private Bitmap getImageBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        URL aURL = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close();
        is.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       //Log.e(TAG, "Error getting bitmap", e);
   }
   return bm;
}
```

}

i am passing the image path  onclick of that position in gridview.but i want to get image path onclick of image.how do i can get image path dynamically and pass another activity.

This is code of my image adapter

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
public ImageView[] mImages;
String qrimage;
static class ViewHolder{

    ImageView image;
}

JSONObject json1= JSONfunction.getJSONfromURL("http://www.zzzzzxxxxxxxxxx.com/app/photo.php");

private Context context;

public ImageAdapter(Context mcontext,JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context=mcontext;
    this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];


    for(int i=0;i<imageArrayJson.length();i++){

        JSONObject image;
        try {
            ImageView imageView;
            imageView = new ImageView(context);

            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(90, 90));
            image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
            qrimage="http://www.aaa.com/"+image.getString("thumbsize");

            //imageView.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap(qrimage));
            mImages[i]= new ImageView(context);
            mImages[i].setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap(qrimage));
            mImages[i].setTag("Image"+i);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to pass something between activites, you're going to want to do something like this:

[How do I pass an object from one activity to another on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906925/android-how-do-i-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another)

You're getting your data from a database, but nothing should change.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .I want to get clicked image url and pass to another activity

Comment: it is working.but know question is arise how can i get clicked image url so that i can use the parcelable

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information. What have you tried?


Also, I suggest that since I answered your regular question, that you mark my answer as complete and create a new one. Since this one is so old not many people are going to come across it.