# Android Development: Accessing LinkedList of objects (defined in Application class) from Main activity

Tags: java, android, object, linked-list

Following on from an earlier thread, I had wondered about creating linkedlists and have them be persistent across multiple activities. It was suggested that I extend the application class to do this so I decided to look into it.

I have since done this, assuming I haven't made a mess of it, the app should now fill in a linkedlist with some example data that I had hoped to use in the main activity. But I can't seem to access the data, and I'm a bit stumped.

Just getting started with android development so sorry if this is a ridiculous question. Anyway here is what i have so far.

The extending class **GlobalData**

```
package com.example.employeeList;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import android.app.Application;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.employeeList.Employee;

 public class GlobalData extends Application {

 public LinkedList<Employee> EmployeeList;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    createEmployeeLinkedList();
 }

  public void createEmployeeLinkedList(){
    // create a linked list
    Employee emp1 = new Employee("John");
    Employee emp2 = new Employee("Bob");
    Employee emp3 = new Employee("Fred");

    LinkedList<Employee> EmployeeList = new LinkedList<Employee>();
    EmployeeList.add(emp1);
    EmployeeList.add(emp2);
    EmployeeList.add(emp3);

     // The following code works, used for testing to see if linklist was actually being created.
     // Employee boo = newEmployee();
     // Employee boo = EmployeeList.getFirst(); 
     // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "("+boo.name+")" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

 }
```

**Employee** class

```
package com.example.employeeList;

import android.app.Application;

 public class Employee extends Application{

  public String name;

  public Employee(String name) {
     this.name = name;
  }
}
```

**MainActivity** class

```
package com.example.employeeList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.employeeList.Employee;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected GlobalData globalData;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get the application instance
    globalData = (GlobalData)getApplication();

    //Would have thought I could just do this but apparently not.
    Employee boo = globalData.EmployeeList.getFirst();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "("+boo.name+")" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }
}
```

The offending lines appear to be

```
 Employee boo = globalData.EmployeeList.getFirst();
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "("+boo.name+")" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making GlobalData a singleton from Application class adding in your GlobalData class something like:

```
    private static GlobalData singleton;

public static GlobalData getInstance() {
    return singleton;
}
```

then you don't need class Employee to extend Application too, its just a data model class.
Then you will have a instance of you GlobalData class (only one instance) in all the app live cycle, so you just can call in every activity/class/etc in you app something like:

```
GlobalData.EmployeeList.get(0)
```

or some stuff like that, as simple as that.

Notice that your GlobalData class will be instantiated when your app start and in the OnCreate method you will create your list and it will be "alive" all the app execution time. You can use the OnPause and OnResume methods from the Application class too in your class to interact with the app state changes.

Hope its help.

Comment: Isn't what i have already technically doing this in regards to the singleton? I had thought about scrapping the separate class for Employee and just doing it inside the GlobalData class with some methods.

Comment: well yes and no, i don't know exactly what you want to achieve, just give you a working example of what i thought you want based on the example (names included). My point is that you don't need to do: `globalData = (GlobalData)getApplication();` just use your class directly in you app, its instance exist in your entire app, i mean that with the code i put there you can just do directly `GlobalData.EmployeeList.getFirst();` in every place you need it

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at Parcelable.

An other post mentionned it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906925/android-how-do-i-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another).

An example [here](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.ca/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html).