# Switching between activities without losing custom data

Tags: android, android-intent

Currently using an Intent with startActivity() to switch between 2 activities which share an abstract superclass. However, whenever startActivity() is called the custom object inherited from the abstract superclass gets reset. Is there anyway to maintain this object between startActivity() calls? Serializing the object with OnSavedInstanceState does not work because this object contains a LinkedList.

Comment: This post might help you with your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755204/android-development-accessing-linkedlist-of-objects-defined-in-application-cla#14756467

Comment: I would stay away from @AndreFernando answer. That is a Serializable implementation and the data is not cleared on garbage collection. It is very bad practice in most cases. Even if it is shared across the app, it's best to create a storage for data rather than Serialize a list of data.

Answer (score 0):

Every time a class is created regardless if it extends a superclass (in this case an Activity), the superclass is recreated. You would extend the Activity to share common methods/functions and imports....

You want to stay away from Serializable, so you want your object class to implement Parcelable:

```
public class CustomObject implements Parcelable {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.name);
    }

    public CustomObject() {
    }

    protected CustomObject(Parcel in) {
        this.name = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<CustomObject> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<CustomObject>() {
        @Override
        public CustomObject createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new CustomObject(source);
        }

        @Override
        public CustomObject[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CustomObject[size];
        }
    };
}
```

In the first activity you want to pass the List to the second Activity using an Intent:

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
        findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(StartActivity.this, ReceiveDataActivity.class);
                i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("KEY", getCustomObjectList());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<CustomObject> getCustomObjectList() {
        ArrayList<CustomObject> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject();
            customObject.setName("Name " + i);
            itemList.add(customObject);
        }
        return itemList;
    }
}
```

Then to get the list you would use getIntent():

```
public class ReceiveDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive_data);
        List<CustomObject> itemList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("KEY");
        Toast.makeText(this, "List size = " + itemList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```