# Android ListView, each row display it's own content inside another ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a `ListView` populated with some text ( phone models in my case, ex: Samsung A, B, C...) and an image ( loaded from URL using android-query ).
When a row is selected, a `ViewPager` will be created along with 3 Tabs ( **Specs**, **Info**, **Img** ), both fragments **Specs** and **Info** are displaying a `ListView` and the last fragment, **Img** is displaying a `GridView`. I'm having no issues with the last fragment, but only with the first 2, as I don't know how to populate the `ListView` so it will display the content for the selected row.

Is it possible to specify for each row a different string array?

If not, how can I achieve this:

[image]

As you can notice in this example, **Samsung D**, has more informations than the previous one.

[image]

This is the main ListView's ClickListener:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("id", position);
                TabStripAdapter newFragment = new TabStripAdapter();
                newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Are you using main ListView's onClickListener?

Comment: **Yes** you can specify for each row a different data to display in your ViewPager.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Use an Custom ArrayAdapter.You can find nice tutorials regarding that [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: @dhun Yes I am using it to start the ViewPager and to pass data

Comment: okay, each time you call onClickListener, based on the item id, pass custom array adapter. Listview is totally dynamic, it can add as many rows as you want. You have the control.

Comment: This is harder than I first thought, I'll see if I can get it done tomorrow. In the mean time maybe someone can provide some code so I can understand better what I have to do. Thanks!

Comment: @Rami can you show me an example?

Comment: You just need to pass the data with bundle (like you did in your `onItemClick`), then in `onCreate()` method of the fragment you get this data ( e.g `Bundle bundle=getArguments();` and `int id = bundle.getInt("id", 0);` ). Finally you load the details of your object (front camera, back camera, storage...) depending on the `id` and build the view.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the on `OnItemClickListener` for your main `ListView` and you will have 3 options:

1. Having an array of objects in the main listview, but only display the model name or the info you want, so when the user select the item just get the object from the position and pass the values (object atributes) to the other activity.
2. Having an array of objects in the main listview, but only display the model name or the info you want, so when the user select the item just get the object from the position and pass the object to the other activity.
3. Having an two atributes object array (itemId, itemName) at the first activity and when the user select the item, pass the itemId to the next Activity, and from the 3-tabed activity ask (to the web service or database) for the info from the item you have the Id.

It should look something like this:

```
    MainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {  
 //       String selectedProductId = MainListArray.get(position).getId(); //Option 1 & 3
 //       String selectedProductInfo = MainListArray.get(position).getInfo ();
// ...more attributes  //Option 1
 //       CustomObject selectedProduct = MainListArray.get(position); //Option 2.
         Intent i = new Intent(_myContext, newActivity.class);
//         i.putString("productId", selectedProductId); //Option 1 & 3.
//         i.putString("productInfo", selectedProductInfo); //Option 1.
// ...more attributes //Option 2.
 //       i.putParceleable("product", selectedProduct); //Option 2.

         startActivity(i);
        }

});
```

For passing a complete object look  at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906925/android-how-do-i-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another), it will show you how to do it.

Comment: Check my question, I've added the ClickListener for the main ListView.