# Trying to class data from fragment to activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, gson

I am trying to pass a custom class (Custom class is Juice), from a fragment to an activity. I saw an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18847945) but it is not working when i am trying to turn the json string back into a Juice object. Here is my code with the error message

Fragment

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), SelectionActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(juices.get(position));
            Log.e("tree",json);
            intent.putExtra("position",json);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Activity

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("position")!=null) {
        String position = getIntent().getStringExtra("position");
        Juice juice =gson.fromJson(position, Juice.class);
        TextView textTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectedTitle);
        textTitle.setText(juice.getName());
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selected);
        imageView.setImageResource((int) juice.getDrawable());

        TextView textDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectedDescription);
        textDescription.setText(juice.getDescription());
    }
```

Error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.intellidev.******/com.intellidev.*****.SelectionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.intellidev.******.Juice.getDescription()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: @DhavalPatel updated with error

Comment: What is **ob** in **ob.getDescription()**? Is it a object of Juice? If yes then you should replace it with juice.getDescription().

Comment: @DhavalPatel done. error persists.

Comment: Have you checked error is coming from which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also access your class object from fragment to activity using implementation of Serializable.

```
class Juice implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2310640779687082782L;
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public String setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public String setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}

Intent mIntent = new Intent(this,SelectionActivity.class);  
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();  
mBundle.putSerializable(SER_KEY,juice);  
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

where at SelectionActivity you can access it like...

```
Juice juice = (Juice)getIntent().getExtra().getSerializable(SER_KEY);
```