# How I pass by refernece object between activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, pass-by-reference

Can I pass by reference object between activity in Android , How ?

Thankyou

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is a **lazybone**. No effort is shown in googling for `android pass object by reference between activities`

Comment: yes, if your object is a custom `Binder` class, but it is a risky stuff, as it its a "live" object and your sending activity can be dead in any time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have googled it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906925/how-do-i-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android), [this](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/passing-data-between-activities.html) or [this](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/passing-objects-between-activities.html)

You can use these examples if your objects implements Parcelable or Serializable. Unfortunaley it is not possible to send an object be reference. You can get around this problem be sending te object back:

returning the object:

```
Intent result = new Intent();
result.putExtra("NAME", myEditedObject);
setIntent(result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

reading the returned object:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
            if (b != null)
                myObject= (MyObject) b.getParcelable(STRING_NAME);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thumbs up for many good ?thises?!

Comment: Thank , but I want to pass by reference between class , putExtra is pass by value not pass by reference.

Comment: Thankyou very much, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

If your object implements Parcelable or Serializable, then the answer is yes.
Just put the object in the intent that you're going to use to display the activity.

Comment: Can object that implement Parcelable or Serializable pass by reference between activity ?

Comment: @WuttipongKhemphetjetsada by reference you can only pass `Binder` objects

Comment: Ok, thankyou  do you have example ?

Comment: @WuttipongKhemphetjetsada see `Bundle#putBinder(String key, IBinder value)`

Comment: Thankyou verymuch , @pskink