# create object then set fields across multiple activities

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Here I am using three simple java classes named `Person` , `MainActivity` and `SecondActivity`.

**Person.class**

```
String name, gender;
int age;
//setters and getters below, code not shown
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
Person person = new Person(); //object created
person.set_name("John Legend");
```

**SecondActivity.class**

```
person.set_age(20); 
person.set_gender("male");
```

Apparently, `SecondActivity.class` will cause a `NullPointerException` because it is pointing to a `null` object reference. How do I tell `SecondActivity.class` that I am referring to the `Person(John Legend)` and set the objects fields of `Person` **John Legend**?

I spent two days looking at this problem.

Comment: Create method in SecondAcitivity and pass Person object as parameter. Also folow naming convention for setter getter of the vairables

Comment: all three are differnt class. either you should pass the object `person` as an arguments to the other class method.  **OR** there is another way to inject objects using Spring framework. :) Thank You

Comment: So how are you trying to reference `person` in your `SecondActivity`? You need to implement `Parcelable` interface and pass your pojo through an `Intent` - any advice to use `static` is a bad idea.

Comment: For your reference you can check [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android?rq=1)

Comment: I imagine that John Legend parameter is a String, because it doesn't have double quotes in the code

Comment: @albert, my mistake. A newbie's typo error. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You have instantiated a new Person object with variable name `person` in MainActivity, but not in the SecondActivity. Therefore it is null in SecondActivity.

If you want to get the name of the person in the MainActivity but set the age and gender in your SecondActivity maybe you could pass the name string with an intent into the SecondActivity and add it when you create a Person object there. Read about intents [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

Answer (score -2):

You should have to create a constructor in SecondActivity class and pass the person object by parameter:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

  Person person;

  public SecondActivity(Person person){
    this.person = person;
  }

}
```

And after pass the person:

```
Person person = new Person(); //object created
person.set_name("John Legend");
SecondActivity sActivity = new SecondActivity(person);
```

Also, before you use person, you can check that is not null:

```
if (person != null) {
   // code ...
}
```

Comment: how to retrieve Person object that is set in SecondAcitivity, it shoud return Person object

Comment: you can make a getPerson function that return person to retrieve the person in the secondActivity. Look for getter/setters information

Comment: In android I think there are intent methods to pass variables, it should better to use them. This is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906925/how-do-i-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android

Comment: Firstly I think you should establish if `SecondActivity` extends `Activity` and if a content view is associated.  If so you should never instantiate a `Activity` class -the Framework should do this.