# java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<ph.com.sdsolutions.colfinancial.app.IntentContentActivity> has no zero argument constructor

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have two Activity class one that is holding the value from the class, second the one who is retrieving the value. I am trying to pass the variable to another Activity class via constructor.

Here is the intent in the 1st activity class

```
  val intent = Intent(activity, IntentContentActivity(quote)::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("intentFragment", i.toString())
                startActivity(intent)
```

I tried to debug it so I can see if the data has been passed and it does [here what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXar9.png) as you can see the `Quote@6908` are passed but still return to me this error. Can someone tell me whats going on here?

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<ph.com.sdsolutions.colfinancial.app.IntentContentActivity> has no zero argument constructor
```

Comment: `val intent = Intent(activity, IntentContentActivity::class.java)`

Comment: The issue is actually in your `IntentContentActivity` class. You can't give Activities constructors with arguments. They are instantiated by the operating system.

Comment: oh ok, any idea how can I pass the quote?

Comment: thanks for a good explanation @nukeforum

Comment: Passing objects between Activities is accomplished either by parcelizing them and putting them in an Intent, or by persisting them (via database or SharedPreferences) and retrieving them once the next Activity starts.

Comment: thank you very much for making it so clear, but last question. I found [this] tutorial and I applied it like this ` val b = Bundle()
                b.putParcelable("pase",quote);` but it doesn't work 

 
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906925/how-do-i-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android)

Comment: @nukeforum you there?

Comment: nvm I have solved it Thankyou very much sir @nukeforum ur the best!