# Android: How to pass ArrayList<customObject> between Activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

How can I pass a Object: ArrayList from one Activity to another?

Seems that intent cannot hold custom ones except ArrayList.

As a kind of hack, I use a static member:

```
staticResultList = new ArrayList<SingleExamResult>(m_examResults);
```

and Get it in the following Activity by:

```
m_examResults = DoExam.staticResultList;
```

It's not the correct way obviously, any 'common' approaches? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid using the static member hack, your custom class, `SingleExamResult`, must implement the `Parcelable` interface:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Comment: Thanks! I found a comprehensive answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441871/passing-data-of-a-non-primitive-type-between-activities-in-android