# passing array list value into tab host but null value error?

Tags: android, string, arraylist

Hi I am trying to pass my `ArrayList` value into my `TabLayout` but I am getting null value please help me...I successfully passed my string value but `ArrayList` value only null...

here I am trying to pass my string and `ArrayList` value..........

this is my code:

```
sdcardImages.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ParxmlActivity.this, tabview.class);
                intent.putExtra("spec",model_List.get(position).spec);
                intent.putExtra("mimage",model_List.get(position).mimage);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("imageList", model_List.get(position).imageList);

                startActivity(intent);  

            }
        });
```

the 1st and 2nd value working fine....spec and mimage but imageList only i am getting null value......

```
public class tabview extends TabActivity {
    Bundle tab_intent;
    public static String spec, mimage, imageList;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewtab);
        tab_intent=tabview.this.getIntent().getExtras();
        spec=tab_intent.getString("spec");
        mimage = tab_intent.getString("mimage");
        imageList =  tab_intent.getString("imageList");
```

above code I am try to get my values the `ImageList` value only shows `null` what is the reason?

code:

```
package ml.ml;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class schild {
    public String name;
    public String model;
    public String spec;
    public String mimage;
    //public String imageList;
    //public String videoList;
    public ArrayList<String> imageList;
    public ArrayList<String> videoList;


    public schild(){
        name = new String();
        model = new String();
        spec = new String();
        mimage = new String();
        imageList = new ArrayList<String>();
        videoList = new ArrayList<String>();
        //imageList =new String();
        //videoList = new String();

    }


}
```

here I am adding to separate `ArrayList`

```
for(int j = 0; j<model_List.size(); j++){

                mname_List.add(model_List.get(j).name);
                mmimage.add(model_List.get(j).mimage);
                mspec_List.add(model_List.get(j).spec);
                mvideo_List.addAll(model_List.get(j).videoList);
                mmimage_List.addAll(model_List.get(j).imageList);
            }
```

this is value I am trying to passing in tab host.......

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939331/android-how-to-pass-arraylistcustomobject-between-activities

Comment: interesting ... in first Activity you're putting StringArrayList and in second you're expecting to get a String ... seems like you do not understand your own code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `tabview` class:

```
ArrayList<String> imageList;
...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    imageList =  tab_intent.getStringArrayList("imageList");
    ...
}
```

**Upd:** You're trying to take **`String`** from Bundle where is **`ArrayList<String>`** located.

Comment: error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<String> to String

Comment: change declaration of imageList

Comment: ok i changed ArrayList<String> imageList; now also i am getting error:The method getStringArrayList(String) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments 
 (ArrayList<String>)

Comment: What and where did you changed? You shouldn't get this error.

Comment: http://paste.org/45205 see this link i am getting error i changed  to upd format sergey......error in this line = imageList =  tab_intent.getStringArrayList(imageList); error = The method getStringArrayList(String) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments 
 (ArrayList<String>)

Comment: Do you know Java language? Right code looks like this: `imageList =  tab_intent.getStringArrayList("imageList");`

Comment: sorry i'm beginner no error now......i wish to show this value in spinner in my audio.java tab host file...last help please.....

Comment: Ask new question about spinner.