# How to add selected(checked) checkedtextview to arraylist and take tat arraylist to next activity ?

Tags: android

```
   public class ListViewActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

ArrayList<String> datas;
DBhelper query;
//ImageView image;
CheckedTextView cap;
DBhelper db;
ArrayList<byte[]> image;
ArrayList<String> caption ;
ArrayList<String> description ;
ArrayList<String> rate ;

ByteArrayInputStream imageStream;
String d;
Bitmap theImage;
ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter;
Button order, menu;
byte[] temp_image;
ArrayList<String>   completedTasks;

Intent i;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
    order = (Button) findViewById(R.id.order);
    order.setOnClickListener(this);

    db = new DBhelper(this);

    image = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    caption = new ArrayList<String>();
    description = new ArrayList<String>();
    rate = new ArrayList<String>();
            // to retrieve the datas from database
    db.open();
    Cursor cursor = db.getEvents("data");
    if( cursor.moveToFirst())   {
        do{

            temp_image = cursor.getBlob(1); //retrieving the image
            //Log.e("image", temp_image.toString());// 
            String temp_caption = cursor.getString(2);//retrieving the data
            Log.e("name", temp_caption);
            String temp_description = cursor.getString(3);
            Log.e("desc", temp_description);
            String temp_rate = cursor.getString(4);
            Log.e("rate", temp_rate);
            //imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(temp_image);
            image.add(temp_image);
            caption.add(temp_caption);
            description.add(temp_description);
            rate.add(temp_rate);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext()) ;
        String[]   captionArray = (String[]) caption.toArray(
                new String[caption.size()]);// convert the 

                     arraylist to arrays.
                     // Adapter to set data to the list.
        itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(
                ListViewActivity.this, R.layout.datalist_item,
                captionArray);
        setListAdapter(itemsAdapter);//set the adapter

        return ;
    }
    db.close();// database close
}
```

Adapter class which extends base adapter.
    private class ItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        String[] items;

```
    public ItemsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] items) {
        this.items = items;
    } 


    public View getView(final int POSITION, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        TextView tvDescription;
        TextView tvRate;

        View view = convertView;
        ImageView img;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) 
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.datalist_item, null);

        } 
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivDatas);

        cap = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
        tvDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvdesc);
        tvRate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRate);
        theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image.get(POSITION), 
                    0, image.get(POSITION).length );
        img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Log.e("ghhf", String.valueOf(imgid));
                //Bundle b = new Bundle();
                Log.e("tag", 
                     String.valueOf(image.get(POSITION)));
                i = new 
                      Intent(ListViewActivity.this,ImageActivity.class);
                //b.putParcelable("imagePath", 
                      image.get(POSITION));
                i.putExtra("imageP", image.get(POSITION));
                //i.putExtra(image.get(POSITION));

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        img.setImageBitmap(theImage);

        cap.setText(caption.get(POSITION));
        tvDescription.setText(description.get(POSITION));
        tvRate.setText(rate.get(POSITION));


        return view; 
    }


    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.length;
    }


    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
}
```

Here i have a problem, when the checkedtextview is checked,I have to add checkedtextview to the arraylist. but here when i am going to select two checkedtextview, Its add only one value to arraylist which ever is selected last.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    String s = caption.get(position);
    //ArrayList<Long> completedIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
    completedTasks = new ArrayList<String>();
    cap = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
```

Here i have to take the selected textview and add to the arraylist, and send the arraylist to the next activity and display it.

```
    if(!cap.isChecked())    {


        Log.d("checked", "true");

        completedTasks.add(s);
        cap.setChecked(true);
        Log.d("true", s);

        return ;    

    }

    else    {
        cap.setChecked(false);

        Log.d("unchecked", "true");
        //for(String str : caption )    {
        completedTasks.remove(s);
        Log.d("false", s);
        //}
        //itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return ;


        //}
    }



}
```

Here we have to display the checked arraylist.

```
         public void onClick(View v) {
    for(String str : completedTasks)    {
        Log.d("selected", str);
    }

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try moving this line: `completedTasks = new ArrayList<String>();` outside of your `onListItemClick`. Move it to onCreate or something. The issue is that each time you click on your listView, it remakes the same object. That's probably why you only see one string in your array.

I suppose you're also having issue putting the arrayList to another activity. Personally i'd just make it a static member, but you should know about the other options explained better than i could:

[How do I pass an object from one activity to another on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906925/android-how-do-i-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another)

[Passing data of a non-primitive type between activities in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441871/passing-data-of-a-non-primitive-type-between-activities-in-android)