# Send to Intent an ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, arraylist

I have in an activity an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`, so basically a list of lists.

What I would like to accomplish, is to send from Activity 1 to Activity 2 this List of Lists, so I thought about intents, but I don't seem to be able to find the necessary getExtra().

To be more precise, `questions` contains `Strings` related to a question, and the corresponding position in `answers` contains all the selected answers to that question.

```
public class ReviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> answers = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_review);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    questions = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("questions");
    answers = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("answers");

}
```

This is how I put the original `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` in the intent:

```
 Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, ReviewActivity.class);
                            mIntent.putExtra("questions", questions);
                            mIntent.putExtra("answers", answers);
                            startActivity(mIntent);
```

The code gives an error at the line `answers = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("answers");`and I understand why, but how can I make a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: here is solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324741/bundle-arraylist-arraylistinteger?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList` is `Serializable` so you can send it to bundle as Serializable.

```
 mIntent.putExtra("answers", answers);
```

To Get List :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list= (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("answers");
```