# How to pass 2D ArrayList from one activity to another

Tags: android

I have a 2 dimensional ArrayList and I want to pass it from one activity to another activity in an android application. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use putSerializable arrays are serializable.

Comment: putSerializable is not working in case of 2 Dimensional Arraylist

Comment: You should include some code or more detail to support your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a static variable in any class that can be something kind of (Tools class) and stock your nDim array and use it where you want, or create your custom class that must implement  `Parcelable` interface, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1441919/1889341) from android master.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

And after this while passing the data to the Intent as extras, use

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("arry_extra", arrayList);
```

and recieve the same in the other Activity using,

```
arrayList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("arry_extra");
```