# Unexpected behavior when passing parcelable data to other activity from an adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter, parcelable, android-bundle

I have an Adapter which uses some custom object list. I wanted to pass the clicked object's to the other activity. So I made the object class implement `Parcelable`.

*To send the data from the adapter*

```
view.findViewById(R.id.play_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), YouTubePlayerActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("data", movie));
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

*To receive the data in the destination activity*

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<Video> videos = b.getParcelable("data");
```

But when I run it, it would pass nothing. 
I tried passing other simpler values like strings and integer and they were too not passed.

Then I had to achieve the task by creating interface. And it worked. But I still don't understand this unexpected behavior when starting activity from adapters. Can you please answer the reason behind this unexpected behavior?

Comment: what does `movie` represents? is it a single object or a list?

Comment: seems a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441871/passing-data-of-a-non-primitive-type-between-activities-in-android

Comment: @AtefHares it is a list. I know i made a typo while typing the code here. But It didn't matter what I pass