# Send data from an arraylist from one activity to another so it can be used for an recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to send data from an array list from one activity to another so that I can put it into a recycled view and display it I sadly don't have any code and I'm trying to find a nice headstart any ideas?

I've tried on a resume once but that did not work well

I'm trying to send data from an array list to a recycler view in another activity and display it.

Comment: For some other ideas - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1441919/3145960

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("arrayListVenue",arrayListVenue);
```

```
intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("arrayListVenue");
```

Use this will work.